# Angular - Show or Hide based on Dropdown list value

Tags: angular

I want my Dropdown list to show/hide Div based on the value selected

I have a dropdown list and several Div in my angular project as shown in the code

```
<div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
                    <label>Reply Type</label>

                    <select class="form-control select2" formControlName="replytype" type="text" style="width: 100%;">
                     <option value="predefined">Predefined</option>
                     <option value="opentype">Open Type</option>
                    </select>           
              </div>
```

Div1

```
                      <div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
                        <label>Application Name</label>
                        <input type="text" formControlName="applicationname" class="form-control" id="applicationname" placeholder="Application Name">
                        <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.controls['applicationname'].touched && form.controls['applicationname'].hasError('required')">
                            Application Name is required! </span>
                      </div>
```

Div2

```
                <div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
                  <label>Main Menu</label>
                  <input type="text"class="form-control" id="mainmenu" placeholder="Message Text">
                </div>
```

If the selected value is predefined then Div1 is visible and Div2 is hidden, but if it is opentype then Div2 is visible and Div1 is hidden.

By default, the Div1 value should be opentype and Div2 should be visible

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here I've used **ngModel** in the dropdown so, that you can get the value which you've selected from the dropdown.

```
<div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
                    <label>Reply Type</label>

                    <select class="form-control select2" formControlName="replytype" type="text" style="width: 100%;" [(ngModel)]="optionValue">
                     <option value="predefined">Predefined</option>
                     <option value="opentype" selected>Open Type</option>
                    </select>           
</div>
```

and in Ts file, you need to declare one variable called optionValue like this:

```
`optionValue`;
```

and now you can use **ngIf** for show/hide Divs.

Div1

```
<ng-container *ngIf="optionValue == 'predefined'>
 <div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
                    <label>Application Name</label>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="applicationname" class="form-control" id="applicationname" placeholder="Application Name">
                    <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.controls['applicationname'].touched && form.controls['applicationname'].hasError('required')">
                        Application Name is required! </span>
                  </div> 
</ng-container>
```

Div2

```
<ng-container *ngIf="optionValue == 'opentype'"
<div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
              <label>Main Menu</label>
              <input type="text"class="form-control" id="mainmenu" placeholder="Message Text">
            </div> 
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I should declare **optionValue** as what type of variable?

Answer (score 4):

You can add a variable that controls the selected value. For example **selectedType**, then, use **ngIf** to hide or show the elements.

**In the .component.ts**

```
  selectedType = 'opentype';

  onChange(event) {
    this.selectedType = event.target.value;
  }
```

**In the html**

```
<div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
  <label>Reply Type</label>

  <select (change)="onChange($event)" formControlName="replytype" class="form-control select2" type="text" style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="predefined">Predefined</option>
    <option selected value="opentype">Open Type</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div *ngIf="selectedType == 'predefined'" class="col-md-12 no-padding">
  <label>Application Name</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="applicationname" class="form-control" id="applicationname" placeholder="Application Name">
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.controls['applicationname'].touched && form.controls['applicationname'].hasError('required')">
    Application Name is required! </span>
</div>

<div *ngIf="selectedType == 'opentype'" class="col-md-12 no-padding">
  <label>Main Menu</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mainmenu" placeholder="Message Text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use ***ngIf** to `show/hide` div based on selected value

Try this:

```
<select class="form-control select2" formControlName="replytype" type="text" style="width: 100%;" (change)="setReplyTypeValue()">
  <option value="predefined">Predefined</option>
  <option value="opentype">Open Type</option>
</select>
```

TS:

`selectedValue:any`

```
  setReplyTypeValue() {
   // set 'predefined' or 'opentype' based on selected value of the form
    this.replytype = selectedValue
  }
```

DIV1:

```
<div class="col-md-12 no-padding" *ngIf="replytype =='predefined'">
  <label>Application Name</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="applicationname" class="form-control" id="applicationname" placeholder="Application Name">
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.controls['applicationname'].touched && form.controls['applicationname'].hasError('required')">
      Application Name is required! </span>
</div>
```

DIV2:

```
<div class="col-md-12 no-padding" *ngIf="replytype =='opentype'">
  <label>Main Menu</label>
  <input type="text"class="form-control" id="mainmenu" placeholder="Message Text">
</div>
```

Comment: I like this answer because now I have more control over the code, like whether I want want to add some more logic or not. Btw, what am I supposed to do to disable any type of validation on hidden div?

Answer (score 0):

With `replytype` in ts you have two method

```
<div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
    <label>Reply Type</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" [(ngModel)]="replytype" type="text" style="width: 100%;">
     <option value="predefined">Predefined</option>
     <option value="opentype">Open Type</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

First methode with *ngIf; else

```
<div class="col-md-12 no-padding"  *ngIf="replytype === 'predefined'; else #opentype">
    <input type="text" formControlName="applicationname" class="form-control" id="applicationname" placeholder="Application Name">
    <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.controls['applicationname'].touched && form.controls['applicationname'].hasError('required')">
        Application Name is required! 
    </span>
<div>

<ng-template #opentype>
    <div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
      <label>Main Menu</label>
      <input type="text"class="form-control" id="mainmenu" placeholder="Message Text">
    </div> 
</ng-template>
```

Or second methode with ngSwitch (You can have many div to display)

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="replytype">
    <div class="col-md-12 no-padding"  *ngSwitchCase="'predefined'">
        <input type="text" formControlName="applicationname" class="form-control" id="applicationname" placeholder="Application Name">
        <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.controls['applicationname'].touched && form.controls['applicationname'].hasError('required')">
            Application Name is required! 
        </span>
    </div> 

    <div class="col-md-12 no-padding" *ngSwitchDefault>
      <label>Main Menu</label>
      <input type="text"class="form-control" id="mainmenu" placeholder="Message Text">
    </div> 
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

For reactive form we can use

```
form.controls['<fieldname>'].value === 'somecheckvalue'
```

For example:

```
<div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
  <label>Reply Type</label>

  <select (change)="onChange($event)" formControlName="replytype" class="form-control select2" type="text" style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="predefined">Predefined</option>
    <option selected value="opentype">Open Type</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div *ngIf="form.controls['replytype'].value === 'predefined'" class="col-md-12 no-padding">
  <label>Application Name</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="applicationname" class="form-control" id="applicationname" placeholder="Application Name">
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.controls['applicationname'].touched && form.controls['applicationname'].hasError('required')">
    Application Name is required! </span>
</div>

<div *ngIf="form.controls['replytype'].value === 'opentype'" class="col-md-12 no-padding">
  <label>Main Menu</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mainmenu" placeholder="Message Text">
</div>
```